# Are these non isomorphic graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I have graph $A$:

[image]

I have graph $B$:

[image]

Are graph $A$ and $B$ non-isomorphic because?

I think yes, because:

- graph $A$ has $V_{8}$ with degree vertex $4$ and graph $B$ has $V_{8}$ with degree vertex $2$.
- or vertices $V_{8}, V_{1} $ in graph $A$ are neighboring, but in graph
  $B$ vertices $V_{8}, V_{1}$ are not neighboring.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not correct.  For example, your first bullet point only shows that $V_8$ in graph $A$ cannot correspond to $V_8$ in graph $B$.  Why can't there be an isomorphism that takes $V_8$ in graph $A$ to some other vertex in graph $B$?  (I am not saying there is -- I have not checked -- but your argument is not sufficient to prove that the graphs are non-isomorphic.)

Remember, the labels are not part of the graph and are just for convenience in identifying particular vertices.